# Default template parameter with a default value?

Tags: c++

We can have the following and it is valid:

```
template<std::size_t Size = 10>
fn(){...}


template<typename Size = std::size_t>
fn() {...}
```

But how to do this?

```
template<typename Size = std::size_t=10>
fn() {...}
```

Comment: You join the Technical Recommendation committee and make a proposal?

Comment: what's the sense of this?

Comment: What would that mean?  The “value” of `Size` is a type (perhaps `std::size_t`); how would one obtain the 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could require that your parameter be a specialization of std::integral_constant (or some other type that provides both 'type' and 'value' members:

```
template<typename Arg = std::integral_constant<size_t, 10>>
struct foo
{ };
```

but in general I would say the two parameter method is preferable.

Answer (score 7):

A template parameter is either a type or a value, it isn't both.

You can do it with *two* parameters

```
template<typename Size = std::size_t, Size s = 10>
```